# Apache Spark RDD + persist() + laziness

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, lazy-evaluation, execution-time

I'm trying to do some sorting tests with Apache Spark.

```
...
for (...){
   Parts = *Generate some RDDs of Integers with some GBs*
}
// Create a huge RDD of Array[Int]
var rdd = sc.union(Parts).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

// Repartition
rdd.coalesce(partitionsNum).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

// Sort
var rdd = rdd.sortBy(x => x, numPartitions = partitions).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

My goal with this test is record the execution time of the RDD generation (Parts + Union) and the RDD sort. If I want to turn this code into laziness I have to do a **Action** like count ().

How can I make this test laziness with the lowest cost possible? Is the Spark UI the best way to record the execution times?

Comment: sc.union? test laziness, not sure what you mean.

Comment: I generated XXGB RDD of data by the union of small partitions, then I do a coalesce() and sort this RDD. There's no Actions in the code, so I think that the code doesn't execute because the lazy evaluation. I want to know if the transformations are really executing or if i need an action to make them do so. If it does need an action, what's the one that has the lowest cost?

Comment: I have used other method, but I also use the Spark UI. You may want to think of the History Server. count is the typical approach I see. No action is indeed no execution. You can observe nothing in Spark UI.